# How does exposed LiveData dispatch changes when postValue is called on MutableLiveData variable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

In ViewModel :

```
private var _someData : MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
var someData: LiveData<Boolean> = _someData

public fun someMethod(){
    _someData.postValue(true)
}
```

In Fragment :

```
viewModel.someData.observe(this, Observer {
    //change posted on MutableLiveData but this LiveData received the changes.
})
```

Since `someData` and `_someData` are 2 different variables, how the `onChanged()` method of `someData` is invoked even if value is posted on `_someData` and changes are observed for exposed `LiveData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both variables reference the same object. The only difference is that you are exposing a `LiveData` so clients can't modify its value. As it is just one object, when you update `_someData`, `someData` is also updated.